# Difference between const method and method with const attributes

Tags: c++, constants

What is the difference between const at the beginning:

```
const int MyClass::showName(string id){
...
}
```

And :

```
int MyClass::showName(const string id) {
...
}
```

And :

```
int MyClass::showName(string id) const{
...
}
```

Comment: the best solution if you don't need to change `id` or any member is `int MyClass::showName(const string &id) const{`

Comment: I don't think the `const` in the first case does anything. In the second case, it apples to the `string` argument, which then cannot be modified in the function. In the third case it renders the *method* constant, so that it can't modify member variables (except `mutable` member variables, which I don't like anyway).

Comment: `showName(const string id)` means `id` is const. `showName(string id) const` means `*this` is const - the object the member function is called on.

Comment: const on an argument means that the variable is not allowed to change within the function, const on the function means it cannot change member variables of the class (it will not modify the state of the  class). You also might want to pass a `std::string&` to avoid unecessary copying of the string. Returning a const int is not required, the caller gets a copy of the int so can do whatever he wants with it. If it where a reference to int then a `const int&` makes sense since it might refer to a member variable of your class that you dont want the caller to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const` modifies the thing it's next to, like a word like "little". "A little yard with a shed" is different from "a yard with a little shed". Let's look at your code examples:

```
  const int MyClass::showName(string id) {
```

The returned integer is const. This has no effect because the caller receives a copy and had no ability to modify the original anyways.

```
 int MyClass::showName(const string id) {
```

The variable `id` is const. This means that code in showName() like `id += "foo";` will be a syntax error because you aren't allowed to modify `id`.

```
  int MyClass::showName(string id) const {
```

The method showName() is const. Suppose you have member variables of your class, for instance

```
class MyClass {
  int something;
  int showName(string id) const;
}
```

We call showName() a const member function, meaning modifying other parts of the object isn't allowed inside showName(). Writing code in showName() like `something = 1;` is a syntax error because it tries to modify a member of `MyClass`.

Comment: `The returned integer is const. This has no effect because...` - not true for pointers like  `const char* foo()` because the const limits what the caller can do with the pointer unless they do an unsafe cast

Comment: @DaveS `const` in `const char*` is not top-level on the type, so it doesn't have the same meaning. It modifies the `char`, not the `char*`.

Comment: @DaveS `const char *ptr;` and `char *const ptr;` are different. `const int value;` and `int const value;` are the same. In `const char* foo()` the pointer returned is copied. Not the pointed-to data, the pointer itself is copied. The pointer points to a `const char`, so removing that const would indeed change the meaning, as it would point to mutable `char`.